# Creating a pcolormesh with named color values

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot a pcolormesh in Python but rather than detail the number values of each color, like with colorbar, I want to map each number to a string - I only have finite number values - and display them instead. Something like: 0='normal', 1='high', 2='very high', with those srings being displayed instead of the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

One approach loops through the cells and adds a text via a dictionary.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
import numpy as np

mat = np.random.randint(0, 3, (5, 8))
cmap = ListedColormap(['lime', 'orange', 'tomato'])

plt.pcolormesh(np.arange(-0.5, mat.shape[1]), np.arange(-0.5, mat.shape[0]), mat, cmap=cmap)

color_dict = {0: 'normal', 1: 'high', 2: 'very\nhigh'}
for i in range(mat.shape[0]):
    for j in range(mat.shape[1]):
        plt.text(j, i, color_dict[mat[i, j]], ha='center', va='center')
plt.show()
```

[image: example pcolormesh]